# {super_search_total_results} Does Not Parse in EE 2.6.1

Tags: templates, supersearch

Using ExpressionEngine 2.6.1 and SuperSearch 2.1.2

After upgrade the {super_search_total_results} no longer parses. It outputs the following:

"{super_search_total_results} Matches Found" in the HTML instead of parsing the variable.

The {super_search_total_results} tag is supposed to be able to be used inside OR outside the super search loop.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in the 2.1.2 version of Super Search?

Comment: I think the same goes for {super_search_keywords}.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the docs are just out of date. I found that it worked when I moved the tag within the results loop.